# VBA Sort in Excel leaves table contents selected

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have an Excel spreadsheet that hold a leaderboard table on one sheet based on the data in a separate sheet. I monitor a change on the data sheet and then automatically sort the leaderboard table. Everything seems to work fine but the contents of the leaderboard table are left selected after my sort. How do I clear the selection seamlessly without affecting any selection on the data sheet.

I've even been a good boy and done the sort using *With* instead of *Select* command.

Here is what I have:

---

### Sheet2(Code) - Data sheet

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

' Check if the item changed is in group area
If Not Intersect(target, target.Worksheet.Range("F7:H93")) Is Nothing Then
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Leaderboard").SortLeaderboard
End If
End Sub
```

---

### Sheet1(Code) - Leaderboard sheet

```
Sub SortLeaderboard()
Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
Set lo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Leaderboard").ListObjects("Table3")

With lo
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table3[Total]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table3[Name]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Do you mean on the leaderboard sheet, the sorted range is still selected and you want to select a single cell for example `A1`?

Comment: Yes the sorted range is still selected. However, the user is entering data on the data sheet so won't using select move the active sheet. I try that out but I thought using select was frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a quirk of the Table if the sheet isn't active. You can avoid it by using the old Sort method instead:

```
Sub SortLeaderboard()
    Dim lo                          As Excel.ListObject
    Set lo = Me.ListObjects("Table3")

    With lo
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Range.Sort key1:=.ListColumns("Total").DataBodyRange.Cells(1), _
                    Order1:=xlDescending, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
                    Key2:=.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange.Cells(1), _
                    Order2:=xlAscending, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, _
                    SortMethod:=xlPinYin, MatchCase:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding something like

`Worksheets("Leaderboard").Select
Worksheets("Leaderboard").Range("A1").Select
Worksheets("Data").Select`

to select a single cell?